# Dataflow job takes too long to start

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm running a job which reads about ~70GB of (compressed data).
In order to speed up processing, I tried to start a job with a large number of instances (500), but after 20 minutes of waiting, it doesn't seem to start processing the data (I have a counter for the number of records read). The reason for having a large number of instances is that as one of the steps, I need to produce an output similar to an inner join, which results in much bigger intermediate dataset for later steps.

What should be an average delay before the job is submitted and when it starts executing? Does it depend on the number of machines?

While I might have a bug that causes that behavior, I still wonder what that number/logic is.

Thanks,
G

Comment: I had another similar case when no progress was done, but that time I traced it down to be permissions issue. I'll try to reproduce with a large number of instances and update.

Answer (score 2):

The time necessary to start VMs on GCE grows with the number of VMs you start, and in general VM startup/shutdown performance can have high variance. 20 minutes would definitely be much higher than normal, but it is somewhere in the tail of the distribution we have been observing for similar sizes. This is a known pain point :(

To verify whether VM startup is actually at fault this time, you can look at Cloud Logs for your job ID, and see if there's any logging going on: if there is, then some VMs definitely started up. Additionally you can enable finer-grained logging by adding an argument to your main program:

```
--workerLogLevelOverrides=com.google.cloud.dataflow#DEBUG
```

This will cause workers to log detailed information, such as receiving and processing work items.

Meanwhile I suggest to enable autoscaling instead of specifying a large number of instances manually - it should gradually scale to the appropriate number of VMs at the appropriate moment in the job's lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible (and probably more likely) explanation is that you are reading a compressed file that needs to be decompressed before it is processed. It is impossible to seek in the compressed file (since gzip doesn't support it directly), so even though you specify a large number of instances, only one instance is being used to read from the file.

The best way to approach the solution of this problem would be to split a single compressed file into many files that are compressed separately.

The best way to debug this problem would be to try it with a smaller compressed input and take a look at the logs.

Comment: It should be noted that even a single reader should start processing the records as soon as they get decompressed. You should see that the read step output counter increases as the file is being decompressed and read.

Comment: Sure, but in this specific scenario I read from a few hundred of small compressed files